# How to handle Win file server permissions when connecting from Linux?

Tags: linux, samba, file-permissions, active-directory, cifs

**Situation:** We have a file server in Windows Server 2012 R2, and until now the workstations are running Windows.

We are trying to use Linux in some workstations (CentOS 8), since all our apps run on a browser nowadays.

**What we have done:** We managed to join these computers to Active Directory (with `realmd` and `sssd`), and Domain Users con login with their Active Directory credentials on Linux.

**Problem:** However, when we configure `cifs` to access our file server, we have to set manually a  user/pass combination in the config file (it's not the idea for a domain user). In such case, no matter which domain user is logged in on one Linux PC, all read/write actions on the file servers would be according to the same user (the one in the config file), and the same problem occurs with respect to which files the users have access to.

**Questions:** Is there a better solution to this which enforces file permissions? One in which logged in domain users could mount a Windows share with their respective credentials without having them written down on each Linux computer?